# NSPredicate return subquerie'd array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My model:

[image]

I want to get an array of coutries ONLY with cities, names of which contain given part of the word.

I tried:

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<Country> = Country.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(cities, $city, $city.name CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0", givenWordPart)
let countries: [Country] = try! context.fetch(request)
```

But it returns an array of countries with ALL the cities in it.

Comment: Off-topic perhaps but you should also create the opposite relationship between City and Country, a to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to gather your result in two separate collections instead. Create a fetch request for City instead using the same predicate as above but as a normal query instead of a sub-query.

This would return an array of City instances that match your search criteria, to get the selection of countries you could extract them from the cities array

```
//fetch and predicate declaration...
let cities: [City] = try! context.fetch(request)
let countries = Set<Country>(cities.map({$0.country }))
```

This assumes you have defined the inverse to-one relationship from City to Country

Comment: countries will have whole bunch of duplicated ones + its slow

Comment: No duplicates when added to a set as I did. Why would this be so slow compared to your subquery?

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behaviour. It queries for `Countries` and returns the ones matching the predicate. The returned `Countries` still have all their cities and if you want only cities with a specific rule, you'll have to the `cities` collection for each `Country`